# List view with image

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, tableview

My problem is to find best view configuration for my application that have a record in the listView.

[image]

My main.xml has this content:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tabName" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textConnection" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        />
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textTitle" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        />
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/listRecord" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And the my actual row of ListView is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBox"
        android:layout_width="48px"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_height="48px">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried with `TableLayout` but starting the application report an error in the `bindView`.
Can I write my XML code with only textView?
Consider that then I must add the caption of the `ListView` that have three image above each column with number.
Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `ListView` is indeed your best option.

> Can I write my XML code with only textView?

Yes, of course.

I don't see what is your problem actually. You should have an activity layout with the `textConnection`, the `textTitle`, then the 3 images aligned to the right (missing in your layout file), and the listview.
As for the row xml layout, I think it is OK! Just combine it with a simple cursor adapter in your java code, and you're done.

Comment: Thank's for your answer :-) 

My problem is how to align the three image in the "caption" in the top of listView and also align the three image in each row of ListView. I must use the relativeLayout?

Comment: I suggest you use a `RelativeLayout` and make use of `layout_alignParentRight`, `layout_toLeftOf`, `layout_below` in order to position your widgets. You should use Eclipse with the graphical layout editor, it is REALLY easy to setup quickly a good `RelativeLayout` that you just need to tune using XML code after creating it with your mouse.

Comment: Ok, thank's. I have little practice with RelativeLayout. Now i try with this system.